# Adding a featureclass / featurelayer dynamically to a Map or MapResourceManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, arcgis, esri

I'm struggling with a really stubborn problem here.

I have a FeatureClass which I want to add to my map, the problem is that every example I can find requires me to hardcore a servicestring, point to a service or something likewise.

I already have a featureclass so I would like to use that to add a dynamic layer to the map, it's a simple point layer so there shouldn't be any sorta convertion as far as i know.
Is there anyway to add a featureclass or featurelayer to the MapResourceManager in any way?

P.S. I'm quite new to the whole adf world so this might be a newb question :)